# How to change dynamically created label text on dynamically created button click in C# Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I am trying to create some labels and buttons dynamically. I want to change the label's name on dynamically crated button click. When I am writing the button_click method, I can not access the label object directly. How can I do that?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DemoPanel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int lblYVal = 10;
            int btnYVal = 50;

            for(int i = 1; i< 5; i++)
            {
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Text = "test";
                lbl.Name = "test"+i.ToString();
                lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, lblYVal);
                lbl.Visible = true;

                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Text = "Click";
                btn.Name = "textBtn" + i.ToString();
                btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10,btnYVal);
                btn.Visible = true;

                btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.btn_click);


                this.Controls.Add(lbl);
                this.Controls.Add(btn);
                lblYVal += 70;
                btnYVal += 70;
                

            }

        }

        void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //How can i change label text from here.
            //lbl.text //Does Not exist Error.
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = "New text"; //Not changing Label text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Label lbl = new Label();` inside `btn_click` will create a new instance of label instead of finding an existing one. You will have to find the label from existing controls on the form. Looking at your code, you want to change the label next to the button. The button name will give you the hint of what label you want to change. For example,  if you do `Messagebox.Show(sender.Name)` inside the click event, you will find the name of the button that was clicked. Now you will have to build the name of the label based on button and find it to change its text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop you've written knows about the button and the label. You can leverage this to write a click handler that captures the label. It's as simple as changing:

```
btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.btn_click);
```

To

```
btn.Click += (sender, args) => lbl.Text = "Clicked";
```

It doesn't have to be so short. You could, for example do:

```
btn.Click += (sender, args) => {
  if(something > 0)
    lbl.Text = "Did the process because something was > 0";
  else
    lbl.Text = "Can't start the process because something is 0";
}
```

Or if you have a method that "does stuff"

```
void DoTheProcessAndOutputToTheLabel(Label x){
  int i = 0;
  foreach(var thing in things){
    bool success = ProcessTheThing(thing);
    if(success)
      i++;
  }
  x.Text = $"Processed {i} things";
}

btn.Click += (sender, args) => DoTheProcessAndOutputToTheLabel(lbl);
```

Not quite sure, in your comment you said "use the sender" but here this event handler only ever attaches to one button so you don't really need to do anything with the sender because it's obvious which sender is is. For example you might have:

```
btn.Tag = "hello"+i;
btn.Click += (sender, args) => DoTheProcessAndOutputToTheLabel(lbl, (sender as Control).Tag);
```

It will send the word "hello2" in as an argument (if it's the second go of the loop).. but realistically because you know the sender you could form anything:

```
var x = "hello"+i;
btn.Click += (sender, args) => DoTheProcessAndOutputToTheLabel(lbl, x);
```

I only foresee the sender but being useful if something else changes the UI between you setting up and the user clicking the button - for example if they run a process that alters the button Tag, then sure, use the sender to grab the latest value

Comment: This worked. But in my main project, I already used a sender that's why it is showing an error. And also I need to check conditions before changing the label text. So can you suggest a way so that I can get access to labels or any control from the click method?

Comment: I'll need to see examples of what you want to do; the description is a bit vague. I'll make an edit to the post to show how you'd do a multi line method, but some more specific direction on what help you need will be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a dictionary of buttons to labels and use that to find the matching label. Another option would be to associate an index with both button and label and find the label with that.

I'll illustrate the dictionary option to you.

```
Dictionary<Button, Label> mapping = new Dictionary<Button, Label>();
```

...

In your loop,

```
mapping[btn] = lbl;
```

In your handler,

```
((Label)mapping[(Button)sender)]).Text = "some text";
```

Comment: You don't need to maintain a dictionary of controls; the Controls collection of whatever you put the label in will do it for you

Comment: Actually, I never used Dictionary, So I don't understand how can I get value in my handler. I copied your code and It shows an error in the handler that mapping is not declared.